# Is "voids(s)" a synonym of "interstellar-space"?

Tags: discussion

Is the (newly suggested tag) [voids](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voids) a synonym of [interstellar](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interstellar) or [interstellar-medium](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interstellar-medium)?
I am asking since I have not yet observed that term being used by astrophysicists, but that's just my  subsample.

PS: When [searching for `void`](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=void) I see 149 results (as of April 30th, 2021), but the picture is not conclusive here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_(astronomy)

Comment: @called2voyage I understand your comment as a *no*, which implies that I should carefully go through the 149 results and consider adding the appropriate new tag [tag:voids].

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the brief comment. I was trying to respond to something at work so just dropped the link quck.